# Package owner not correctly applied for Debian package created through fpm

Tags: ubuntu, packaging, user-permissions, debian-packaging

I want to create a debian package through the fpm packaging tool and I want this package to be owned by a particular user/group ( say X ). So while building the package, I set the options --deb-user and --deb-group to X. Now this user X might not exist on the system where I'm installing the package. So in the pre-install script of the package, I'm creating the user X .

I installed the package on Ubuntu WSL.
After the package is installed, I notice that the user has been created successfully but the package is not owned by X. I've noticed that sometimes it's owned by root and sometimes by an user 1001 which doesn't even exist on the system.

Can anybody help with this?